# Run method in Timer task is executing two times

Tags: java, timer

I have created a Timer which runs for every 20 seconds. Timer task is taking more than a minute to finish the task. Run method in Timer task is executing two times after 20 seconds before timer task is finished.

```
class A {

    static Timer timer; 

    TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask({
        public void run(){
            if(check for some data in the database before inserting )
            // Insert records into database 
        }
    }

    public test(){
        A.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(imertask,0, 20*1000); 
    }
}
```

Two records of the same data are inserted into the database with the time difference of 14 seconds. I am expecting only one record to be in the database Any help on this so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By intent, if the first execution takes more than 20 seconds, the second execution will start immediately after. If the first execution takes more than 40 seconds, the third execution will start immediately after the second execution.  And so on until you catch up to having approximately N/20 executions after N seconds.

[Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-)

> In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the
>   scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is
>   delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background
>   activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to
>   "catch up." In the long run, the frequency of execution will be
>   exactly the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system
>   clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).

If you're inserting the same data twice, then it seems that problem would be with however you decide whether you've already inserted that data, rather than with the interval between executions.

If the task runs for about a minute, is that indicative of a bug, or just how long it takes (for example to connect to a remote database)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @another-dave. I was expecting until the first task is finished second task will be in the queue. I am inserting data into 30 tables. So it is taking time. After finishing that, I am checking whether there are records or not then inserting a new one. I am totally confused records are getting inserted with time difference of 14 seconds.

Comment: Oh, wait. Maybe I misread your question. The expected behavior is that the 2nd 'run' starts immediately *after* the 1st 'run' completes.  You're saying it runs concurrently?  How did you determine that?   If we consider your '14 sec diff', maybe that record got inserted fairly late in the first run, and then again fairly early in the second run - so on that basis it does not prove the runs were simultaneous.

Comment: It is running concurrently. I have one column in one of the tables which inserts system time. I checked that.  It is 14 seconds difference.

Comment: I tried to explain that I don't think it proves concurrency.  At this point I'd insert print/logging statements as the first and last lines of the 'run' method, including the current time.

Comment: Ya, I think it is not starting at the same time but, after 20 seconds, I think it is starting a new thread and executing timer task

Comment: Did you try reporting the actual time as suggested?  The documentation claims that overlapped execution does not happen. I haven't experimented myself, but I'm inclined to believe the ```scheduleAtFixedRate``` method works the way it says it works.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine

```
class A {

    static Timer timer;

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Task is running");
        }
    };

    public void test() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 5 * 1000);

    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.test();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Abdullah. I forgot to add timer = new Timer(); in my code. It is working fine but when Timer task is taking more than a minute then it is running tow times that is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure why Timer task is running concurrently. I have written same logic and scheduling using Thread and everything is working now.